# How to include different images in my autodesk forge viewer floorplan

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im currently working on a project with the autodesk forge viewer. My viewer is showing an uploaded and converted floorplan. In this plan I would like to show different logos for my rooms from a database. I have made multiple extensions for my viewer already but I have not discovered any possibility for my logo project so far. Maybe you have any ideas for implementing.

Thx,
JT

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to mind is to append an element containing your logos to the canvas - see this blog [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg) to get started.

Basically you'd need to attach images to the rooms' locations hovering over the canvas and subscribe to the camera change event to adjust their locations/coordinates per camera movement. You can retrieve the coordinates of your room by calculating their bounding boxes with their dbid with:

```
function get2DBounds(dbId, model){
    const find2DBounds = function(fragList, fragId, dbId, bc) {
       const mesh = fragList.getVizmesh( fragId );
       const vbr = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.VertexBufferReader( mesh.geometry );
       vbr.enumGeomsForObject( dbId, bc );
    }

    const it = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();
    let bc = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.BoundsCallback( bounds );
    const dbId2fragId = model.getData().fragments.dbId2fragId;
    const fragIds = dbId2fragId[dbId];

    if( Array.isArray( fragIds ) ) {
        for( let i = 0; i < fragIds.length; i++ ) {
            find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds[i], dbId, bc );
        }
    } else if( typeof fragIds === 'number' ) {
        find2DBounds( fragList, fragIds, dbId, bc );
    }

    return bc.bounds;
}

const boundingBox = get2DBounds( dbId, viewer.model );
const position = boundingBox.center()
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach.  I will try it.